# How to timeout Sqlalchemy from database - not timeout database from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy's engine creation [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#supported-databases), there is a pool_timeout; however, this pertains to getting a connection. My questions is, is there a way I can set Sqlalchemy - not the database -  to disconnect from the connection if database has not responded.

To expand, I have a database in a virtual machine (same network), but the VM's memory gets locked when performing queries. I need a way for sqlalchemy to know how long that connection has been open and to disconnect after a set time.

Database: postgres

Thank you.